# snowflake json data flatten in existing table fields

Tags: sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, json-flattener

I have a snowflake table as below

table name: raw_data

| id | conv_type | transcript |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | chat | [{"by":"sys", "text":" can I help you?", "time":"2023-01-01 11:11:11", "comments":""},{"by":"person1", "text":" yes tell me", "time":"2023-01-01 11:12:11", "comments":""}] |
| 2 | phone | [{"by":"sys", "text":" can I help you with?", "time":"2023-01-01 11:13:11", "comments":""},{"by":"person2", "text":" want to know time now", "time":"2023-01-01 12:11:18", "comments":""},{"by":"sys", "text":" time is something ", "time":"2023-01-01 13:11:11", "comments":" no comments"}] |

Need to flattern data like below

| id | conv_type | transcript | by | text | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | chat | [{"by":"sys", "text":" can I help you?", "time":"2023-01-01 11:11:11", "comments":""},{"by":"person1", "text":" yes tell me", "time":"2023-01-01 11:12:11", "comments":""}] | sys | can I help you? | 2023-01-01 11:11:11 |
| 1 | chat | [{"by":"sys", "text":" can I help you?", "time":"2023-01-01 11:11:11", "comments":""},{"by":"person1", "text":" yes tell me", "time":"2023-01-01 11:12:11", "comments":""}] | person1 | yes tell me | 2023-01-01 11:12:11 |
| 2 | phone | [{"by":"sys", "text":" can I help you with?", "time":"2023-01-01 11:13:11", "comments":""},{"by":"person2", "text":" want to know time now", "time":"2023-01-01 12:11:18", "comments":""},{"by":"sys", "text":" time is something ", "time":"2023-01-01 13:11:11", "comments":" no comments"}] | sys | can I help you with? | 2023-01-01 11:13:11 |
| 2 | phone | [{"by":"sys", "text":" can I help you with?", "time":"2023-01-01 11:13:11", "comments":""},{"by":"person2", "text":" want to know time now", "time":"2023-01-01 12:11:18", "comments":""},{"by":"sys", "text":" time is something ", "time":"2023-01-01 13:11:11", "comments":" no comments"}] | person2 | want to know time now | 2023-01-01 12:11:18 |
| 2 | phone | [{"by":"sys", "text":" can I help you with?", "time":"2023-01-01 11:13:11", "comments":""},{"by":"person2", "text":" want to know time now", "time":"2023-01-01 12:11:18", "comments":""},{"by":"sys", "text":" time is something ", "time":"2023-01-01 13:11:11", "comments":" no comments"}] | sys | time is something | 2023-01-01 13:11:11 |

I tried to use below code.

raw_data

```
select
   *,
   a.value:by::varchar as by,
   a.value:text::varchar as text,
   a.value:time::varchar as time
from raw_data
, lateral flatten(input => raw_data:transcript) a;
```

by,text,time values are showing as null, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `parse_json()` as follows :

```
select t.*,
   a.value:by::varchar as "by",
   a.value:text::varchar as "text",
   a.value:time::varchar as "time"
from raw_data t
, lateral flatten(input => parse_json(t.transcript)) a
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have values in JSON array `[]`.

```
select
   *,
   a.value:by::varchar as by,
   a.value:text::varchar as text,
   a.value:time::varchar as time
from raw_data
, lateral flatten(input => raw_data:transcript[0]) a;
```